# ajaxSubmitButton: INSERT issue

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, yii

What I am trying to do here is to insert into a table some values by passing them from AjaxSubmitButton and calling the controller/action.

Here's the controller action first

```
public function actionAddit()
{
        $connection = yii::app()->db;
        $transaction=$connection->beginTransaction();
        try 
        {    
        $connection = yii::app()->db;
        $sql1 = "INSERT INTO apTracker (id, title,createdDate,owner) VALUES(:id, :title,:createdDate,:owner)";


            $command=$connection->createCommand($sql1);

            $command->bindValue(":id", $_POST['id']);
            $command->bindValue(":title", $_POST['title']);
            $command->bindValue(":createdDate", new CDbExpression('NOW()'));
            $command->bindValue(":owner", $_POST['o']);

                $command->execute();
                $transaction->commit();
        }       
        catch(Exception $e)
        {
            $transaction->rollBack();
            $this->refresh;
        }
```

And here's the Ajaxbutton in the view file :

```
 <?php echo CHtml::ajaxSubmitButton('Yes!',          
        array('/entry/addit'), 
        array(
                'type'=>'POST',
                'data' => array('id' => '1','title' => 'Untitled','o'=>'6'),
                'success' => 'js:function(){window.location="site/message"}', 
        ));?>
```

Well, I don't know what exactly is this but it doesn't work. However,if I remove command bindvalue and hardcode some values in the sql query itself, it works. So, I am guessing the issue may be passing the values from the AjaxSubmit part to the controller. I am doing something wrong here, but can't exactly make out what. Any help guys?

EDIT : Okay, Sorry for the edit confusion, the question is back to its original form.

I have already tried out the solution by eggyal, however, I am still not able to get it to work.

Comment: Any javascript errors? How are you rendering the view? Just tried locally, works fine.

Comment: The view is rendered as a modal form (Bootstrap CSS). The AjaxButton is on that modal form. Can that be an issue?

Comment: Depends on how you are rendering it. It needs jquery, so if you are rendering it with `rednerPartial`, then probably that's the issue.

Comment: It's not. It's being rendered as $this->render('index');

Comment: Why are you using SQL anyways? Is $_POST being populated?

Comment: Well, I am a bit more comfortable with plain sql thats why. If that can be a problem I can switch back no issue. Checked with LiveHTTPHeader in Firefox, the data is getting posted.

Comment: The MVC way is preferred if you're using an MVC framework, that's all :) For instance, the best practice is to create a rule for values like NOW() and just forget about them. Could you please post the most recent version of your code, beneath the original version? The error is probably something minuscule, but I can't tell from this :)

Answer (score 1):

1. You're passing the string literal `'NOW()'` as the `:createdDate` parameter, which is not valid.  Just use `NOW()` in the SQL instead:

   ```
   $sql1 = '
     INSERT INTO apTracker (id, title, createdDate, owner) VALUES
       (:id, :title, NOW(), :owner)
   ';

   $command = $connection->createCommand($sql1);

   $command->bindValue(':id',    $_POST['id']);
   $command->bindValue(':title', $_POST['title']);
   $command->bindValue(':owner', $_POST['o']);

   $command->execute();
   ```
2. The second (`$url`) argument to [`CHtml::ajaxSubmitButton`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#ajaxSubmitButton-detail) should be a string, not an array:

   ```
   <?php
     echo CHtml::ajaxSubmitButton(
       'Yes!',          
       '/entry/addit', 
       array(
         'type'    => 'POST',
         'data'    => array('id' => '1', 'title' => 'Untitled', 'o'=>'6'),
         'success' => 'js:function(){window.location="site/message"}', 
       )
     );
   ?>
   ```
3. You're needlessly reassigning `$connection` within your `try` block.

Comment: Good catch. Fixed them both but still no luck. It still won't work. I am editing the original question to reflect these changes.

Comment: @redGREENblue: It's not good to make such changes in the question. You can edit it and add - below your original question - what you have changed and how it (doesn't still) work.

Comment: @redGREENblue: Also, see my (added) point #2 - ypercube's comment probably applies just as much to me!

Comment: With your current edit, someone that reads the question, (that doesn't know the complete history) sees the asnwer by @eggyal as pointless.